# Select data from one table that depends on values from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. First one is `conversion_earnings` and second on is `vloer_sales_orders`

[image]

[image]

I need to get the sum of the `installer_paid_amount` of every installer_id 
from `conversion_earning` table based on selected `created_on` timestamps from `vloer_sales_orders` table where order_id is a match in both the tables. I tried the following query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ce.installer_id, SUM(ce.installer_paid_amount) as sum_installer 
 FROM conversion_earning INNER JOIN vloer_sales_orders so 
 on ce.order_id = so.order_id 
 WHERE ce.vendor_family_id = '10' AND ce.invoice_for = 'Installer' AND 
 ce.installer_id !='' AND so.created_on between '2019-12-01' AND '2020-01-21' 
 group by ce.installer_id 
 ORDER BY SUM(ce.installer_paid_amount) DESC
```

I am getting sql error. How to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - u are missing allias for table conversion_earning and u don't need distinct here since you are using group by

```
SELECT so.installer_id, SUM(ce.installer_paid_amount) as sum_installer 
FROM conversion_earning ce INNER JOIN vloer_sales_orders so 
on ce.order_id = so.order_id 
WHERE ce.vendor_family_id = '10' AND ce.invoice_for = 'Installer' AND so.installer_id !='' AND so.created_on between '2019-12-01' AND '2020-01-21' 
group by so.installer_id 
ORDER BY sum_installer DESC
```

Comment: Still getting sql error `Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'ce.installer_id' in 'field list'`

Comment: @MuntashirAreRahi, I've edited it - you can check now

Comment: `Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'so.installer_paid_amount' in 'field list'`

Comment: @Fahmi you are missing alias name for conversion_earning due to that the query returns invalid field list

Comment: @MuntashirAreRahi, you can check now bro